# processlist information MySQL add more columns

Tags: mysql, processlist

The `processlist` provides very little information for certain thread states (such as sleep state), which makes it very difficult to debug problematic client code.

Adding tracking info in the form of an SQL comment / script name / linenumber etc,  is useless if the INFO column is NULL (as it is in sleep state)

How to add "Last Query" to the `processlist` table?

I use MySQL 5.5.3

Comment: You might be the very first person who needs this. What information do you think you get? What problem would it solve? Just curious, I can't think of a situation, where this would actually be of any use. What does it matter which thread did what? Oh, and to answer your question, it's not possible (except by adjusting the source code).

Comment: I agree with @fancyPants. But you can use special monitoring tools to handle and monitor the last queries. Although it wont be added to your processlist table on your server, but you will surely be able to look into the results on the Monitoring tools. You can use any of the tools like for example [MONyog](https://www.webyog.com/product/monyog) ,MySQL Enterprise Monitor,etc